# SQL WHERE IS NULL or column = 'value'

Tags: sql, sqlite

Currently facing a problem using SQLite3 wherein

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE item_size IS NULL OR item_size = 'S';
```

the above query doesn't work in that it will return only `NULL` values and not `S`.

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE item_size = 'S'
```

the above obviously returns `S`

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE item_size = 'S'OR item_size IS NULL;
```

the above returns only `NULL` values

I'm trying to accomplish the equivalent of below,

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE item_size IS NULL;

SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE item_size = 'S';
```

but in one command,
because of the nature of `WHERE column IS NULL OR column = 'value'`, only ever returns either `NULL` or 'value' due to the nature of null effecting the algorithm,

are there any overarcing/unknown to me SQL laws that'd allow me to bypass `WHERE item_size IS NULL OR item_size = 'S';` fundamentally not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE coalesce(item_size, 'S') = 'S'
GROUP BY  coalesce(item_size, 'S') -- will add nulls to S or
-- GROUP BY  coalesce(item_size, 'null') - will add them as 'null' but filter them out by your where
```

Your problem is that using `sum` does an implicit `group by` - and `null` does not group well with strings - you must explicitly `group by` the coalesced value to group nulls to `S`

Comment: SELECT item_id, SUM(qoh), MIN(price), MAX(price), item_size
FROM inventory
WHERE coalesce(item_size, 'S') = 'S'
GROUP BY  coalesce(item_size, NULL);

worked, thanks